# WordPress - Writing conditional statements for the excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

How can this function be rewritten so that if I'm on the index page, the read more text changes.

```
function wpdocs_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '...' . '<div class="read-more"><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" rel="nofollow">Read More</a></div>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'wpdocs_excerpt_more' );
```

On `index.php` I'd like it to say "Read The Full Article". What if we took it a step further and specified a `wp_query`? That way it's possible to modify it more than once in a template file.

Would it be easier to just remove `.read-more` from this function and using `echo` in my `wp-query`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function wpdocs_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    // depending on how you set up your home page, you will use either "is_home()" or "is_front_page()"
    $more_text = is_home() ? 'Read The Full Article' : 'Read More';
    return '...' . '<div class="read-more"><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" rel="nofollow">' . $more_text . '</a></div>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'wpdocs_excerpt_more' );
```

Reference this if you're not sure you should use `is_home()` or `is_front_page()`: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/when-to-use-is-home-vs-is-front-page

Comment: Is there a default for `$more_text`? What if you're not on the home page what determines the value of the variable?

Comment: `$more_text = is_home() ? 'Read The Full Article' : 'Read More';` This, in plain english says: `if on home page, set $more_text to "Read The Full Article". otherwise, set $more_text to "Read More".` Then, instead of hard-coding `Read More` like in your question, we use the variable `$more_text`.

Comment: Amazing, instead of template file, like `is_home()` is it possible to do it by wp_query? Just looking for flexibility.

Comment: I'm blind, I did not see `: 'Read More';`. This is great man. Thank you so much.

Comment: @DarrenBachan It's been a while since I've worked in WordPress, but I think you can use the function pretty much anywhere. So if you're using `WP_Query` to get posts, then you can still use `is_home()`.